# why there is no Center() method for Rectangle class in c#?

Tags: c#

previously, there is such method for Rectangle in MFC, i dont know why there is not for the c# version.

Comment: I find this to be a strange omission as well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Presumably it wasn't deemed useful enough to merit inclusion.

You could easily add it as an extension method if you want though (and if you're using C# 3):

```
public static Point Center(this Rectangle rect)
{
    return new Point(rect.Left + rect.Width/2,
                     rect.Top + rect.Height / 2);
}
```

Note that as the values are expressed as integers, you could easily end up getting a non-exact value, assuming you want to return a `Point` rather than another structure using `decimal` or `double`.

The above is actually for the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` *struct*. If you're talking about a different Rectangle, please add the appropriate information and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: How to add this extension to System.Drawing.Rectangle?

Comment: @CallMeLaNN: Just declare it in a static, non-generic, top-level class. For more details, read up about extension methods in general, e.g. in MSDN.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93879/system-drawing-rectangle-needs-centerpoint-property is where it has been suggested formally.

Comment: @Evorlor: There still isn't in [`System.Drawing.Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) as far as I can see. Were you thinking of a different `Rectangle` type, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5):

It exists within the (no longer supported) Microsoft.XNA.Framework.

[Rectangle.Center Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.center.aspx)

`myRectangle.Center` returns a `Point`

Comment: in which version? .net 5?

Comment: 4.5.51641 has it.  Not sure when it was added.

Comment: Which exact type are you referring to? A link would be useful.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Eep! I was using Microsoft.Xna.Framework (which I think is no longer supported).  My mistake!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.center.aspx